# margin list after 5 li items with php

Tags: php, list, margin

I hope topic title will be okey, doesnt really find good idea for naming topic. What i want is to produce that my UL list will get some class or margin after a few LI in list.
Something like that

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="2">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Now what i have in code is something like that, but offcourse doesnt work...:

```
$datas = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$countData = count($datas);

for($i = 0; $i < $countData; $i++){
    echo '<ul>';
        $j = 0;
        foreach($datas as $data){
            $j++;
            if($j < 3){
                echo '<li>'.$data.'</li>';
            }
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: "<ul class=$i>" ? If I understand well...

Comment: Yes but what about elements in li? It will copy all same elements and will get only abc abc abc ....

Comment: I need more information to help you. I don't understand what you exactly expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you can try this:

```
$datas = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
echo "<ul>\n";
$class = 0;
foreach ($datas as $i => $data) {

   echo "<li>$data</li>\n";
   if (($i+1) % 3 == 0)
     echo "</ul>\n<ul class=".++$class.">\n";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

It produces:

```
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
<ul class=1>
<li>d</li>
<li>e</li>
<li>f</li>
</ul>
<ul class=2>
<li>g</li>
<li>h</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tnx a lot exactly this is what i need!